# Visual Studio 2019 crash without error notify

Tags: razor, crash, visual-studio-2019

Currently, I updated my visual studio to 2019 version. But I realized every time I use shortcuts "Ctrl + Tab" many times on *.cshtml pages for quickly. My VS will auto crash and start again without error notify. It so inconvenient

What is the issues here and how I can fix it.

I googled for find out solutions, but nothing really helpful. Thanks for your help.

P/s: I updated my VS to newest version, and the problem still occurs, here is my VS version
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem by just reinstall VS